# Windows - constant flickering redraw of old-style windows controls: how to fault-find?

Tags: windows-10, display

On my new PC (windows 10, UHD monitor), I am seeing a constant flickering update, but only on some applications. Generally it seems to be 'old' applications that have issues, like Notepad++ and Irfanview, where they use the old-style Windows Common Controls. Those areas are flickering regularly (once a second or so) and redrawing. I assume something somewhere is sending windows redraw messages for the whole screen, but I can't see how to confirm this. Visual Studio comes with spy++ which should show the messages received by a window, but the one window that you can't spy on is the root/desktop window.

Any ideas on what might be causing this, or how to confirm it?

Here's a little 15sec video of what I'm talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcxHJ7xtVe4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) was the immediate cause, although it does not cause a problem for me on any other system.

Switching f.lux into safe mode resolved the flickering, although the actual root cause seems to be something asking every app on the desktop to redraw when it gets a colour profile change notification.

Comment: Rather old thread, but we managed to get a similar issue using MSWord. Insert a table with multiple rows. Using the mouse, double click any horizontal line of that table. This will broadcast a WM_SYNCDRAW and flicker applications.
Some kind of bug we have to live with..